# Is there a way to auto-increment the version number when build from command line?

Tags: delphi, msbuild

When i build my Delphi project from the command line :

> MSBuild MyProject.dproj /p:Config=Release
>   /p:Platform=Android /t:Build;Deploy

then the version number is not auto-incremented (even if we set this option in the project options of course). Is there a way to increment the version number from the command line?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that without using an external tool.

Comment: @dummzeuch thanks yes it's was i was afraid us, but it's cost nothing to ask. I finally end up by making a little script that before to call msbuild will auto increment the version in the dproj